# alter a trigger with different name

Tags: oracle, plsql, ddl, database-trigger

I have a trigger that is like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER myTrigger
AFTER UPDATE
ON myTable
FOR EACH ROW
```

Can I create an  SQL script that modifies my trigger so that:

- it triggers after an  `update` and after a  `delete`.
- change its name to newTrigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you need to drop and create a new trigger (with new name)

If **name remains** you could recreate it with `create or replace`